# Is there a function for making a new dataframe using pandas to select only part of a word?

Tags: python, contains

I am looking to select all values that include "hennessy" in the name, i.e. "Hennessy Black Cognac", "Hennessy XO". I know it would simply be
trial = Sales[Sales["Description"]if=="Hennessy"]
if I wanted only the value "Hennessy", but I want it if it contains the word "Hennessy" at all.

- working on python with pandas imported
  Thanks :)

Comment: Btw, the correct code for only 'Hennessy' would be `trial = Sales[Sales["Description"]] == "Hennessy"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` keyword to check if a value is present in a sequence.

Like this:

```
 trial = "hennessy" in lower(Sales[Sales["Description"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using str.startswith

```
import pandas as pd
# initialize list of lists
data = [['Hennessy Black Cognac', 10], ['Hennessy XO', 15], ['julian merger', 14]]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
new_df = df.loc[df.Name.str.startswith('Hennessy', na=False)]
new_df
```

or You can use **apply** to easily apply any string matching function to your column elementwise

```
df_new =df[df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.startswith('Hennessy'))]
df_new
```

Comment: This will only work if the value *starts with* 'Hennessy'. The OP's question is for all values that *contains* 'Hennessy'.